# Scipy minimze with constrains that have no simple expression

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize

I am trying to find the values that minimize a least squares function. The issue is that a solution may be *valid* or not in a way that cannot be given as a simple expression of the values. Instead, we can check the validity by calling a function.

What I tried to do was to set the sum of squares to infinity if the solution is not valid, but `scipy.optimize.minimize` does not like that. What's a better way to solve this?

A simplified version of my code:

```py
probs = constant
def sse(a_candidate):
        validity = some_function(a_candidate)

        if not validity:
            sum_sq_err = np.inf

        else:
            ym = function_of(a_candidate)
            sum_sq_err = np.sum((ym-probs)**2)

        return sum_sq_err
a_solution = scipy.optimize.minimize(sse,a0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a [NonlinearConstraint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint.html#scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint) object to `scipy.optimize.minimize`.

```
a_solution = scipy.optimize.minimize(sse, a0, constraints=scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint(...))
```

I cannot provide further details because your question does not provide any detail, and by the same argument I cannot guarantee that imposing a NonLinearConstraint could actually help you.

Comment: Thanks! With a NonelinearConstraint, I'm getting a `Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem`. Is there a different solver than the default I should be using?

Comment: @tmkadamcz I know nothing about the details of your problem, why do you think that I could provide further help? Yes, there are different solvers, they are explained in the Scipy docs, this is [the starting point](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html).

Comment: I will rewrite a more complete question

Comment: @tmkadamcz If you rewrite your question you are going to get much better answers.